# How can I perform string interpolation in a .gpi file?

Tags: string, string-interpolation

I am trying to understand how the .gpi file syntax works.  I did a couple searches on Google and it looks like GPI files were invented by Garmin for plotting GPS points.  My goal is to print the value of a variable.

For example,

```
tag=sprintf("%s", ARG1)

plot sprintf("%s/tags/%s.dat", history_dir, tag) \
    u 1:2 w filledcurve x1 ls 20 t 'Tag ${tag} emitted ', \
 '' u 1:4 w filledcurve x1 ls 21 t 'Packages which emitted ${tag}', \
 '' u 1:3 w filledcurve x1 ls 22 t 'Tag ${tag} overridden'
```

I've tried using `${tag}` but that is only printing the literal value and not the variable value.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Hint: `sprintf` is a C function.

```
tag=sprintf("%s", ARG1)

plot sprintf("%s/tags/%s.dat", history_dir, tag) \
    u 1:2 w filledcurve x1 ls 20 t sprintf("Tag %s emitted", tag), \
 '' u 1:4 w filledcurve x1 ls 21 t sprintf("Packages which emitted %s", tag), \
 '' u 1:3 w filledcurve x1 ls 22 t sprintf("Tag %s overridden", tag)
```